# Would like to identify a late 80s/early 90s lo-pro bicycle's manufacturer and tube type

Tags: identify-this-bike, steel, triathlon, time-trial

I just purchased this bike locally in Southern California and thought it would be straightforward to identify but I've asked around and no one seems to know.

The specs are:

- Lugged steel (fork crown lugs match frame)
- No serial number or builder's mark (likely repainted)
- Mostly SSC/Zap Mavic components (suggesting French or custom build)
- Gipiemme "patent" front and rear dropouts (124.6mm rear spacing)
- Geometry mostly resembles an early Pinarello Prologo (not TT or track version), due to curved seat stays (only lo-pro frame I've seen with this feature!!), shape of upper seat stay tubes and their meeting point on the seat tube lug, but differs in placement of shifter boss, shape of rear drop out, and lack of builder's stamp.
- It has a small peg/tube on the front of the upper seat tube of unknown purpose.
- BB shell is 68mm, unknown threading (until I can remove the Phil Wood BB).

Please see attached photos. Any leads appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get more details from the place/person from whom you bought the bike ?  Looks gorgeous - would be even better with unfaded red/black splash bartape .  Pink doesn't go with the frame :)

Comment: Damn, this bike looks like she was made of PVC, left in the sun for too long and started to melt. It's great! The headtube lugs resemble those that Gazelle (Dutch manufacturer) used for their Champion Mondial frames in the '80. The fork crown is Cinelli aero, at least it's what it looks like. The peg on the seat tube is the pump peg, common in vintage road bikes ('80s and earlier).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! The first thing I did was ask the guy I bought it from. He was selling it for a neighbor who also had no info on it. I had someone suggest it may have been stolen, repainted, and the serial filed off. However, the bike itself looks like it was untouched/unchanged since the early 90s and features a mish-mash of parts. Campy aero shifters, Phil Wood bb, Shimano 105 front derailleur, off brand steel seatpost and seat, 36h Shimano 600 front hub laced to an 18 spoke Hed front rim (who does that!?!), a specialized rear skewer, 7sp Dura Ace 7300 freewheel.

Comment: I found it guys! The builder of this bike is Toronto-based Jo Gardin! Look up the "signature TT" or "crono" models. Canadian with Oria tubing. Woohoo!

Comment: @M.Hernandez If that's the answer, write it as an actual answer below and then accept it, to earn yourself some stackexchange points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is definitely a Gardin TT pursuit frame. It has been independently verified. Thanks all! I learned a lot about Mississauga (Toronto) Canada-based Joe Gardin frames in the process.

Comment: See here: https://www.pedalroom.com/bike/gardin-signature-ttpursuit-5072

Answer (score 1):

from [Varying wheel sizes on triathlon bike](https://www.bikeforums.net/22043682-post3.html)

> This is my funny bike.700 c rear and 24 inch junior on front. The headtube angle on your example suggests it is indeed a TT frame. It was to get your back horizontal but still having a frame big enough to carry a strong rider.
> Chris Boardman riding this configuration still holds the World Record for an hour, set in 1996 thereabouts.

[[image: https://cimg9.ibsrv.net/gimg/bikeforums.net-vbulletin/2000x1504/img_20200612_155855_7f73532e251bb90367c981f4a62d76897e46ebca.jpg2]

Comment: A nice find, but the OP was asking if we could identify the bicycle *manufacturer*, and if possible what tubeset was used in construction. This response describes a style of bicycle.

Comment: FORK looks like Columbus, dont know about E.G. Bates, below better hint

Answer (score 1):

[Gardin Team Cannella Funny Bike](https://www.pedalroom.com/bike/gardin-team-cannella-funny-bike-44840)

..
[image]

Comment: Interesting - its definitely the same design of frame, but the markings/decals are different to the other example.  Also this fork is just-about straight whereas the other fork has much more rake to it.   Excellent find !